# plot symetric autocorrelation

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to calculate and plot the result in symetric axis (-x:0:x)
However i can only get the result on x-axis from 0:x
anyway i'm trying to simulate the LA code autocorrelation and cross correlation for LAS cdma

the code that i'm using  :

```
Ko = 38;
n = 0:10;
for i = 1:length(n)
    x(i) = Ko*i+i*(i-1);
end

for n = 11
    x11 = x(10)+(Ko+22);
end


for n = 12  
    x12 = x11+(Ko+24);
end

for n = 13
    x13 = x12+(Ko+30);
end

for n = 14
    x14 = x13+(Ko+34);
end

for n = 15
    x15 = x14+(Ko+38);
end

pulses = [x, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15];

spaces = 0:808;
samplespace = zeros(1,length(spaces));
samplespace(1) = dd(1);
samplespace(39) = dd(39);
samplespace(79) = dd(79);
samplespace(121) = dd(121);
samplespace(165) = dd(165);
samplespace(211) = dd(211);
samplespace(259) = dd(259);
samplespace(309) = dd(309);
samplespace(361) = dd(361);
samplespace(415) = dd(415);
samplespace(471) = dd(471);
samplespace(531) = dd(531);
samplespace(593) = dd(593);
samplespace(661) = dd(661);
samplespace(733) = dd(733);
samplespace(809) = dd(809);

LA_pulse = [samplespace];
otocor=LA_pulse;
N=length(otocor);

y=otocor;
z=otocor;

for i=1:N-1
    for i=N-1:-1:1
        otocor(i+1)=otocor(i);
    end
    otocor(1)=0;
    z=[z; otocor];
end;

m=[z]*[y'];
m=m/N;
m2=fliplr(m)
stem(m);
```

how can i plot the results from `-808 : 808` and symetric at `0` x-axis ?
as i'm not really sure if i'm doing it right here to calculate autocorrelation for LA code in LAS cdma too

Comment: Please fix you line spacing in your code, also some comments would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can' test it, but try this:

```
m_sym = [fliplr(m), m];
stem(linspace(-808, 808, numel(m_sym)),m_sym)
```

Comment: many thanks, i got the autocorrelation code from some blog
I will try the suggested solution and get back with the result

Comment: I already try and they give me error result
??? Error using ==> stem at 44
The length of X must match the number of rows of Y.

Error in ==> dirac at 82
stem(linspace(-808, 808, numel(m_sym)),m_sym)

so i change the code a bit




m_sym=m':




m_sym=fliplr(m_sym):




stem(linspace(-808, 808, numel(m_sym)),m_sym):




however the result is different from what i imagined
i want to have the stem plot result from 0:808 and have the mirrored result at -808:0
(sorry i don't know how edit the code in this comment at the moment to make it easy to see)

Comment: @user3247431: Is `m` vertical or horizontal? You can use ` on both sides of the code-segments in comments.

Comment: I transpose the matrix from vertical to horizontal




\\`m_sym=m';`\\
\\`m_sym=fliplr(m_sym);`\\
\\`stem(linspace(-808, 808, numel(m_sym)),m_sym)`\\

Comment: @user3247431: Do: `m_sym = [fliplr(m'), m']` and try again.

Comment: Btw, the code you posted is **very very bad**, so don't use it to understand how to write MATLAB code! Unfortunately, I don't have time to show the right way to do it.